# Does Code Review require OPs to provide an MRE?

Tags: support, scope, code-length

I read and searched the Help Center. But I didn't find anything about [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Does it mean that Code Review doesn't require MREs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code Review is not Stack Overflow.

If you look under the "Asking your question" section of the [How do I ask a good question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) help topic, you'll see that it says that you can leave supporting, but non-essential, code in links to other sites. With a Minimal, Reproducible example on Stack Overflow this is not permitted (as all of the code required to reproduce the problem should be included in the question). Including a MRE can cause reviewers to comment on code that you are not interested in getting reviewed, and might cause you to get fewer reviews (as a long block of code takes longer to review, and not everyone can spend the time to review it).

What you do need to provide is an explanation of what the code does, and all of the code that you want reviewed.

Comment: One question, without MRE, how can the reviewers comfirm his answer just do the same with old code? Or in code review(not just this site, general speaking code review), the reviewers just provide suggestion, but no need to provide the runable and correct code with details?

Comment: @leaf_yakitori You're welcome to provide a small usage example, but the core of the program should be posted as-is as much as possible for a good review. The character limit of a post is over 65k, a lot of programs and descriptions will fit in there.